# Why is my tick so large?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

In the upper left corner, you can see that the tick is 148ms, it should be lower than 50ms. It makes the animal (or entity) move laggy (and it's also laggy while eating and sleeping).

It should not depend on the number of animals, because I already tried to kill all the animals but it still didn't help.
I was using the same computer and creating 400 animals on another map and the tick didn't rise up to 100ms.

Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Are you using any mod?

Comment: Or do you have any other programs/apps running?

Comment: I didn't use any mod and closed all the browsers. 
now I find that when I leave this region, the tick becomes normal. I do admit that there are many animals, but they're even more before I upgrade to 1.9.3, the tick was still normal. ((I already stop all Redstone mechanisms))

Comment: I forgot my villagers(around 60)! After I killed all the villagers, the problem was solved. (I don't think 60 is a large number...) But I still want to know why the villager that existed in the previous version of Minecraft will not course the tick to be so large, I still want to keep them. (they are useful in some sense)